# Evaluation of the variable when defining a function

Tags: python

Can anybody explain me why this two blocks of python code do not give me the same results when I am evaluating the functions in the list :

Block 1:

```
fct_list = []
theta = [[-2.95,0.001], [-0.5,0.511], [-0.1,0.51], [-2.95,0.001]]
for i in range(4):
     def fct(lcs):
         return some_func(lcs, beta=theta[i][0], sigma=theta[i][1])
     fct_list.append(fct)
```

Block 2:

```
def fct_1(lcs):
    return some_func(lcs, beta=-2.95, sigma=0.001)

def fct_2(lcs):
    return some_func(lcs, beta=-0.5, sigma=0.511)

def fct_3(lcs):
    return some_func(lcs, beta=-0.1, sigma=0.51)

def fct_4(lcs):
    return some_func(lcs, beta=-2.95, sigma=0.001)
fct_list = [fct_1,fct_2,fct_3,fct_4]
```

It seems that the parameters are not evaluated in the first case, and it uses the value of theta in the memory when the function is executed.

I would like the value of beta and sigma to be hard coded in the function, like in the second case, but with the values of the parameters evaluated  when the list is built. Does anyone know how to do that ?

My current approach consists in writing the block 2 in a separate file in order to have the numerical values of beta and sigma hard coded at the moment when I'm building the list. Is there a cleaner way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is that you are re-defining the function on each
iteration step which also applies to the previous functions
in the fct_list... 
the builtin functools library actually has a nice function for your purpose (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

def some_func(x, beta, sigma):
    return [x , beta , sigma]

fct_list = []
theta = [[-2.95,0.001], [-0.5,0.511], [-0.1,0.51], [-2.95,0.001]]
for i in range(4):

     fct_list.append(partial(some_func, beta=theta[i][0], sigma=theta[i][1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are building your list `fct_list1` through the loop, your variable `i` is **closure** and is "remembered" in inner function `fct()`. But this variable `i` is remembered through the reference, so when you change it (and through iteration you will change it), the final value is `3`. See the example, I added print in inner function `fct`:

```
fct_list1 = []
fct_list2 = []
theta = [[-2.95,0.001], [-0.5,0.511], [-0.1,0.51], [-2.95,0.001]]

def some_func(l, beta, sigma):
    print(l, beta, sigma)

for i in range(4):
    def fct(lcs):
        print(i)
        return some_func(lcs, beta=theta[i][0], sigma=theta[i][1])
    fct_list1.append(fct)

def fct_1(lcs):
    return some_func(lcs, beta=-2.95, sigma=0.001)

def fct_2(lcs):
    return some_func(lcs, beta=-0.5, sigma=0.511)

def fct_3(lcs):
    return some_func(lcs, beta=-0.1, sigma=0.51)

def fct_4(lcs):
    return some_func(lcs, beta=-2.95, sigma=0.001)

fct_list2 = [fct_1,fct_2,fct_3,fct_4]


for f in fct_list1:
    f(theta)

print('-' * 80)

for f in fct_list2:
    f(theta)
```

Output:

```
3
[[-2.95, 0.001], [-0.5, 0.511], [-0.1, 0.51], [-2.95, 0.001]] -2.95 0.001
3
[[-2.95, 0.001], [-0.5, 0.511], [-0.1, 0.51], [-2.95, 0.001]] -2.95 0.001
3
[[-2.95, 0.001], [-0.5, 0.511], [-0.1, 0.51], [-2.95, 0.001]] -2.95 0.001
3
[[-2.95, 0.001], [-0.5, 0.511], [-0.1, 0.51], [-2.95, 0.001]] -2.95 0.001
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[-2.95, 0.001], [-0.5, 0.511], [-0.1, 0.51], [-2.95, 0.001]] -2.95 0.001
[[-2.95, 0.001], [-0.5, 0.511], [-0.1, 0.51], [-2.95, 0.001]] -0.5 0.511
[[-2.95, 0.001], [-0.5, 0.511], [-0.1, 0.51], [-2.95, 0.001]] -0.1 0.51
[[-2.95, 0.001], [-0.5, 0.511], [-0.1, 0.51], [-2.95, 0.001]] -2.95 0.001
```

One of the solution is slightly modify your code in loop:

```
for i in range(4):
    def fct(lcs, index):
        return some_func(lcs, beta=theta[index][0], sigma=theta[index][1])
    fct_list1.append(lambda lcs, index=i: fct(lcs, index))
```